# React-BreadCrumbs does not pick up variable from method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router, breadcrumbs

I have a multi-page web application running with reactjs. 
I'm trying to define a custom react-breadcrumb for a specific page
which involves extracting a value and using that in the breadcrumb

Running the code with the below, I can see that console picks up jobName
But if I look at the breadcrumbs, I'm stuck with

```
home > templates > Missing name prop from Route
```

I don't quite understand why the variable isn't being picked up for the router. If I just hard code it in, it will work. Any advice?

```
getTemplateJobName(templateId,dateChosen){
    doGetJobById({jobId: templateId,reconDate: dateChosen}).then(
    ({body: template})=>{ 
        let {jobName: jobName}=template;
        console.log(jobName);
        return jobName;
    });
},

render(){
  return (
    <div>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route name='home' path={'/'+contextName}>
            <IndexRoute  component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route name='templates' path='templates'>
                <IndexRoute component={JobPage}/>
                <Route path=':reconDate&:templateId' component={JobDetailPage} staticName={true} getDisplayName={(params) => this.getTemplateJobName(params.templateId,params.reconDate)}/>
            </Route>
            <Route name='report' path='report' component={ReportPanel}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Router>
```

Comment: you are not returning the value on getDisplayName prop. Try `getDisplayName={ (params) => ( this.getTemplateJobName(params.templateId,params.reconDate) )}`

Comment: @bennygenel doesn't seem to have made a difference sadly. Still prints to console, but don't see it in breadcrumbs (home > templates > Missing name prop from Route)

Comment: Could it be that the promise function is not correct?

Comment: @bennygenel Perhaps it is about synchronous vs asynchronous?

Comment: yeap. Its definitely because of that. My mistake. I missed the promise function. You can set a state value rather than returning a value and set the `getDispalayName` prop to that state value.

Comment: @bennygenel not quite sure what you mean. You're suggesting I modify the method to e.g. replace the console.log() line with this.setState({jobName: JobName}); and then replace the return with return this.state.jobName?

Comment: I tried the above, although I still get the same issue with:
home > templates > Missing name prop from Route

Comment: I tried putting the whole promise function inside the setstate where the method return is outside of it. ended up getting two errors,  1) Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.  react.js:20541:9
2) TypeError: this.state is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this please;

```
export default App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      DisplayName: ''
    };
  }

  getTemplateJobName(templateId,dateChosen) {
    doGetJobById({jobId: templateId,reconDate: dateChosen}).then(
      ({body: template})=>{ 
        let {jobName: jobName}=template;
        console.log(jobName);
        // return jobName; 
        this.setState({ DisplayName: jobName });
      }
    );
  }

  getDisplayName(params) {
    this.getTemplateJobName(params.templateId,params.reconDate);
    return this.state.DisplayName;
  }


  render() {
    return 
    (<div>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Route name='home' path={'/' + contextName}>
          <IndexRoute  component={LandingPage}/>
          <Route name='templates' path='templates'>
            <IndexRoute component={JobPage}/>
            <Route path=':reconDate&:templateId' component={JobDetailPage} staticName={true} getDisplayName={ this.getDisplayName.bind(this) }/>
          </Route>
          <Route name='report' path='report' component={ReportPanel}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path='*' component={NotFoundPage}/>
      </Router>
    </div>)
  }
}
```